# Data in a browser application only backed by a file server

Tags: javascript, html, fileserver

Morning everybody. Before anything, please forgive my english as it's not my mother tongue ! But I do speak HTML5, CSS3, Javascript and php among others...

To enhance performance at work I'm thinking about a single page browser app. Being linked to the military, the IT guys are quite "locked" :

- all I have access to is a basic file server where the normal user has
  read/write authorisation,
- we're stuck with legacy browsers (IE 8 and Firefox 17) so no file/blob API,
- they **don't allow the use a web server** (so no apache or nginx...) or the installation of software.

In order to make the thing maintanable, I would wish to separate the data from the main page. How can I handle data persistence ?

From a read only perspective, my best guess so far is to embed all the data I need at the bottom of my index.html... Not very classy !

From a read/write perspective, no clue yet !

Thank you for your help.
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the control over the security settings of Internet Explorer, one option to explore is to use the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) scripting object, eg:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
var tf = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\temp\\mytest.txt", true);
tf.WriteLine('Hello World!');
tf.Close();
```